# Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission but i cant An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (58FCB30C)

Tags: console, playback

i am try to uplaode my app but

Errors, warnings and messages

Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console.

then i go to
App content -> Advertising ID

try to select No or yes alwase return

An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (58FCB30C)

[58FCB30C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp1vq.png)

save sucssess and coutenu

Comment: Have you come up with any solution? The same issue here.

Comment: I was using Firefox browser
So I switched to Chrome browser and it worked @Zahra

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tarik Zaeem, I did the same the day I asked the question, though. It worked for me as well.